# Why does Rust compile my project again with `cargo build --release` followed by `cargo run`?

Tags: compilation, rust, rust-cargo

[Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html) teaches us that `cargo build` creates a binary file  after compiling, which we can execute with `cargo run`. `cargo run` will again compile the code if it notices any change after `cargo build` command is executed. It also says that `cargo build --release` command creates the final program, which will run faster.

My question is, why is that when I do `cargo build --release`, it compiles the code, which is fine. But when I execute `cargo run`, it again compiles the code, even though I haven't changed any code since. It is working normally with `cargo build`, followed by `cargo run` i.e compiling one time with the former command.

```
naufil@naufil-Inspiron-7559:~/Desktop/rust/20April/variables$ cargo build
   Compiling variables v0.1.0 (/home/naufil/Desktop/rust/20April/variables)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.35s
naufil@naufil-Inspiron-7559:~/Desktop/rust/20April/variables$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running `target/debug/variables`
Hello, world! 6
naufil@naufil-Inspiron-7559:~/Desktop/rust/20April/variables$ cargo build --release
   Compiling variables v0.1.0 (/home/naufil/Desktop/rust/20April/variables)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.34s
naufil@naufil-Inspiron-7559:~/Desktop/rust/20April/variables$ cargo run
   Compiling variables v0.1.0 (/home/naufil/Desktop/rust/20April/variables)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.23s
     Running `target/debug/variables`
Hello, world! 6
```

Comment: If you run `cargo build --release` and then `cargo run --release`, does it recompile too?

Comment: @Cerberus no it doesn't. Thanks. The documentation doesn't teaches that

Comment: If you look a bit at the run times, you can see it just checks to see if there are new changes, but it exits imediately because it doesn't have changes. Then it just runs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**`cargo run` attempts to run the debug build of your project. Use `cargo run --release` instead.** A `cargo build --release` followed by `cargo run --release` won't compile again.

Cargo maintains two pretty much completely independent sets of build artifacts:

- The debug build, stored in `target/debug/`
- The release build, stored in `target/release/`

---

All of these sub-commands allow you to specify which of these profiles to use (not necessarily an exhaustive list):

- **Default: debug** (switch to release mode with `--release`)

  - `cargo build`
  - `cargo run`
  - `cargo test`
  - `cargo check`
- **Default: release** (switch to debug mode with `--debug`)

  - `cargo bench`
  - `cargo install`